Display waveform with ability to zoom on both axes preferably without rendering whole waveform in python
I'm looking for a library or tool to setup an oscilloscope-like interface in my python program. Ideally I want a hassle-free solution with the matplotlib level of engagement as this would only serve to check the waveform in human friendly way for sanity's sake. I looked through the matplotlib's pyplot documentation but didn't find anything useful. But given how common that problem seems, I imagine there are some handy libraries to do it.

"matlab's pyplot" - You mean matplotlib?

@wjandrea, yeah you are right! sorry, my head is a mess. Gonna fix it now
